# How to invert a symmetric Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider the following equation, for $1\leq i\leq n$,
$$
y_i=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=\max(-k,1-i)}^{\min(k,n-i)} x_{i+j}
$$
which, for each $i$ and $k$, gives the sum of the terms within an index radius $k$. The $\max$ and $\min$ conditions exclude indexes outside $[1,n]$ For example, with $n=4$ and $i=2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_2=\sum_{k=0}^4 \sum_{j=\max(-k,-1)}^{\min(k,2)} x_{i+j}=4x_1 +5x_2+4x_3+2x_4
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, we may alternatively write
$$
y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n (n+1-|i-j|)x_j
$$
In matrix form, with $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_n)^T$ and $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$, we have
$$
\mathbf{y}=
A_n\mathbf{x}
$$
where
$$
A_n=
\begin{pmatrix}
n+1 & n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 2\\
n & n+1 & n & n-1 & \cdots & 3\\
n-1 & n & n+1 & n & \cdots & 4\\
\vdots &  &  &  & \ddots & \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & n+1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For which $n$ is $A_n$ invertible?